# How to check if cell data exist in two different dataframes rows

Tags: pandas, python-2.7

I have two files. They already sorted by first column.
I need some how check if row data from first file equals (or exist) to the same row in second file.
If data not exist (meaning new value or was changed) I would like to update both files with " ".

Example

old

```
col1 col2 col3 col4

val1 val2 val3 val4
val5 val6 val7 val8
```

new

```
col1 col2 col3 col4 
val1 val2 val3 val4
val9 val5 val6 val7
```

Result

old_updated

```
col1 col2 col3 col4 col5
val1 val2 val3 val4 nan
     val5 val6 val7 val8
```

new_updated

```
col1 col2 col3 col4 col5
val1 val2 val3 val4 
val9 val5 val6 val7
```

I already tried isin for series

Comment: show us code for what you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a start using pandas merge with the *indicator* flag set to True. This will add a column telling you what the source of that row is.

```
dfnew = pd.DataFrame([["x","y","z","t"], ["a","s","b","e"]], 
                     columns=("col1","col2","col3","col4"))
dfold = pd.DataFrame([["x","y","z","t"],["d","a","b","t"]], 
                     columns=("col1","col2","col3","col4"))

df_merge = pd.merge(dfnew, dfold, how="outer", indicator=True)
>>>
  col1 col2 col3 col4      _merge
0    x    y    z    t        both
1    a    s    b    e   left_only
2    d    a    b    t  right_only
```

With an outer join you'll see everything. You can do a `how="left"` if you only want the `dfnew` rows represented.

From here you can mask on the `_merge` column etc, as you see fit. Your use case isn't clear so this should get you going.